# Alternative a "chiusura tra virgolette"?

Tags: idioms, phrase-request

Ci sono altri modi di dire "chiusura tra virgolette" in italiano corretto?

Ero sicuro che "racchiudimento tra virgolette" fosse uno ma pare proprio di no ([1](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/7081/racchiudimento)).

Anche "quotare" mi pare sia meglio lasciarlo fuori.

#### Edit:

Solo a titolo informativo, in questo momento l'espressione mi serve in un contesto di programmazione software: ho messo delle virgolette attorno a una parte di codice e deve esprimere in modo sufficientemente chiaro che sono stati messi proprio dei caratteri di virgolette.
Pertanto sono meno interessato a espressioni ambigue.
La domanda però rimane generica, rischio di far restar fuori cose interessanti se la limito con un soggettivo "preciso"; vi avverto solo, giusto perchè non ci restiate male, che mostrerò meno entusiasmo per le proposte equivocabili.

Per domande del genere mi pare sia giusto accettare una risposta (magari wiki) con un elenco completo, probabilmente fra qualche giorno; nel frattempo darò solo upvote.

Comment: Se puoi riformulare quello che devi dire in modo da usare un verbo anziché un nome, sembra tutto più semplice: “virgolettare” come detto in una risposta o anche appunto “racchiudere fra virgolette”. E “citazione”/“citare” (che è poi il significato di *to quote*) è adatto al contesto?

Comment: @DaG Anche se preferisco un nome mi può andare anche un verbo, al participio passato.    
Come puoi capire dall'edit alla risposta "citare" decisamente non andrebbe; tra l'altro "to quote" ha anche un senso esatto di mettere tra virgolette, è quello il senso che intenderei se stessi scrivendo in inglese e lo volessi usare (come facilmente farei, "to quote" è ambiguo sul tipo di quotazione ma nel mio caso attuale è una questione poco importante).

Comment: Grazie per il chiarimento (e occhio, che “[quotazione](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/quotazione/)” non vuol dire “citazione” ;-) ).

Comment: @DaG Lo so, ma "quotare" come italianizzazione di "to quote" è decisamente definitivamente entrato nell'italiano "internettiano"; lo si usa prevalentemente con il significato di citare, ma l'ho visto anche con quello di virgolettare, o meglio di "escapare" (to escape non so proprio come si potrebbe dire in italiano)

Comment: La domanda sarebbe molto più chiara se ci scrivessi direttamente la frase che vuoi riformulare...

Comment: @FedericoPoloni La frase completa era "Chiusura tra virgolette di due percorsi", non credo aiuti molto di più. Era per il titolo di un commit, precisamente. Comunque ormai rimane quella per quello che mi serviva, anche se mi interesserebbe ancora sapere le eventuali alternative.

Answer (score 4):

You may use the verb ***[virgolettare](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/virgolettare.shtml)***:

> - Racchiudere un testo tra virgolette: *virgolettare una parola straniera*

from which: [virgolettato](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/V/virgolettato.shtml):

> • agg. Inserito tra virgolette
>   • s.m. Testo inserito tra virgolette

Sabatini Coletti

Comment: Come mai in inglese?

Comment: @DaG - Because we are an international site.

Comment: Oh, I was under the impression that there were some of a [consensus](http://meta.italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1/should-we-allow-questions-answers-to-be-in-italian) to “answer in English to a question posed in English and in Italian to a question posed in Italian”. In particular, when an Italian asks in Italian a question about Italian and an Italian answers, it sounds quite funny that the answer is in English (and the OP might well not speak English, at that).

Comment: Thank you, I hadn't thought of that. I'll probably not use it for my present necessity though, it seems a little too distant from what I want to convey, I think a lot of readers would not be instantly sure of its meaning.